Detecting that a \label-ed section does not have a section number
I regularly have sections; such as the exec summary that do not have a chapter or section number; e.g. \chapter*{Summary} - that I need to refer to.
I would like to refer to normal sections with a \S\ref{foo}, page \pageref{foo} -- but drop the empty \ref{foo} for sections that do not have a counter.
Example below sums it up - the final output is shown - with the empty string shown. How would one detect that \ref{valid-label} does not have a usable counter ?

With the code below. I had hoped that an \ifempty would work. But alas.
\documentclass[11pt,a4,final,abstracton]{book}

\def \ifempty#1{\def\temp{#1} \ifx\temp\empty }

\def\whstring{} % holds the final/full scring

\newcommand\wh[1]{\label{#1}%
        \expandafter\def\expandafter\whstring\expandafter{\whstring{}, #1 (%
            \ifempty{\ref{#1}}%
                % Do not print the reference - as it is empty. This
                % does not seem to work.
            \else%
                \S\ref{#1}, %
            \fi %
            p\pageref{#1}%
        )}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Summary} % Intentionally no chapter number.

This is sometext\wh{Good stufff}

\chapter{Introduction} % Normal chapter with counting of sections, etc.
\section{one}

This is more sometext\wh{Bad stuff}

\chapter{Comments}

Comments processed\whstring.

\end{document}


Are you familiar with the \hypertarget/\hyperlink cross-referencing mechanism that's provided by the hyperref package? Do please have a look at this answer [shameless self-citation alert!] to the query How to cross-reference an unnumbered theorem using hyperref and cleveref for a practical application of the \hypertarget/\hyperlink mechanism to unnumbered theorem-like environments. The basic idea is applicable to unnumbered chapters and sections as well.

The trouble with that is that \label uses \@currentlabel to set the label. Starred sectioning commands do not run \refstepcounter, which is the one responsible for setting that. So whatever value is in \@currentlabel it is not cleared either for a starred \chapter. Hence, if any other document element has called \refstepcounter ungrouped (e.g. a previous numbered \chapter), you'll get that value, it won't be empty.

you can use the refcount package to access the label values in an expandable way, but as @gusbrs wrote, as soon as you have another chapter before the one you are referring to the value will not be empty anymore.

If you just want to reference unnumbered sections in this way, you can define \@currentlabel to be a special string for each unnumbered section (the internally used command is \@schapter) and check if \getrefnumber{<label>} of refcount equals this string upon expansion. Note you can't use \ref because it is not expandable; \getrefnumber is.
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{refcount}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook{cmd/@schapter/before}{\def\@currentlabel{UNNUMBEREDCHAPTER}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\whref}{m}
  {
    \tl_if_eq:enTF { \getrefnumber{#1} } { UNNUMBEREDCHAPTER }
      { \S,~p.\,\pageref{#1} }
      { \S\ref{#1},~p.\,\pageref{#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Summary}\label{foo} % Intentionally no chapter number.

This is some text

\chapter{Introduction}\label{bar} % Normal chapter with counting of sections, etc.
\section{one}

This is more some text

\chapter{References}

\whref{foo}

\whref{bar}
\end{document}

But the use case in your example seems different. It seems you just want to compose a sequence of notes that are processed at the end of the document into a printed list. I say this because your \wh commands are not placed immediately after \chapter, but in the middle of the chapter body. So all you need is the value of \thechapter and the page number at the time of the note. Since \thechapter is not updated for unnumbered chapters, we can define a command \whchapnum which is \thechapter for numbered chapters (using \@chapter) and empty for unnumbered chapters (using \@schapter).
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\AddToHook{cmd/@chapter/after}{\protected@edef\whchapnum{\thechapter}}
\AddToHook{cmd/@schapter/after}{\def\whchapnum{}}
\seq_new:N \g_wh_notes_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\wh}{m}
  {
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \whchapnum
      {
        \seq_gput_right:Ne \g_wh_notes_seq { \exp_not:n {#1}~(\exp_not:N\S,~p.\,\thepage) }
      }
      {
        \seq_gput_right:Ne \g_wh_notes_seq { \exp_not:n {#1}~(\exp_not:N\S\whchapnum,~p.\,\thepage) }
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\whstring}{}
  {
    \seq_use:Nn \g_wh_notes_seq { ,~ }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Summary} % Intentionally no chapter number.

This is some text\wh{Good stuff}

\chapter{Introduction} % Normal chapter with counting of sections, etc.
\section{one}

This is more some text\wh{Bad stuff}

\chapter{Comments}

Comments processed: \whstring.

\end{document}


Sorry, but this is not going to work. You cannot trust the contents of \@currentlabel unless immediately after a \refstepcounter (or if you set it yourself).
The \label will pick up the current value of \@currentlabel; your first \label has an empty value for \@currentlabel, but just by chance.
By the way, your \ifempty command will always return “not empty”, unless you call \ifempty{} (but this obviously defeats its purpose).
You apparently want to refer to the last \chapter, independently on any other counter and possible resetting of \@currentlabel in between.
With the following code, I use a specific replacement for \@currentlabel that's set to empty with \chapter* and to the chapter number for numbered \chapters.
The item in \wh is stored in a sequence that's eventually delivered with \whstring, items separated by a space.
The command \wh also does a \refstepcounter so we have a good place anchor for \pageref and provides for an automatic \label (it's not a good idea to use arbitrary text in a \label.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,final]{book}

\NewCommandCopy{\latexchapter}{\chapter}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% * version
    \latexchapter*{#3}%
    \tl_gset:Nn \g_gulik_wh_current_tl {} % empty for unnumbered chapter
  }{% numbered chapter
    \latexchapter[#2]{#3}%
    \tl_gset:Ne \g_gulik_wh_current_tl { \arabic{chapter} }
  }%
}

\tl_new:N \g_gulik_wh_current_tl
\tl_new:N \l__gulik_wh_item_tl
\seq_new:N \g_gulik_wh_items_seq

\newcounter{wh}

\NewDocumentCommand{\wh}{m}
 {
  \refstepcounter{wh}
  \label{wh@\thewh}% for \pageref
  \gulik_wh:nVe {#1} \g_gulik_wh_current_tl {wh@\thewh}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \gulik_wh:nnn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__gulik_wh_item_tl {#1~(}
  \tl_if_blank:nF {#2}
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__gulik_wh_item_tl {\S#2~}
   }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__gulik_wh_item_tl { p.~\pageref{#3}) }
  \seq_gput_right:NV \g_gulik_wh_items_seq \l__gulik_wh_item_tl
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gulik_wh:nnn {nVe}

\NewDocumentCommand{\whstring}{}{ \seq_use:Nn \g_gulik_wh_items_seq {~} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Summary} % Intentionally no chapter number.

This is sometext\wh{Good stufff}

\chapter{Introduction} % Normal chapter with counting of sections, etc.
\section{one}

This is more sometext\wh{Bad stuff}

\chapter{Comments}

Comments processed \whstring.

\end{document}


